# wildcard on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

simple question I want to wildcard

MCS023A  MCS345B MCS123G

why neither

```
    ls MCS[1-9][1-9][1-9]*
```

nor

```
    ls MCS[:digit:][:digit:][:digit:][:alpha:]
```

works, which gives me error

```
    No such file or directory
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ls MCS[1-9][1-9][1-9]* works:

```
$ touch MCS023A MCS345B MCS123G
$ ls MCS[1-9][1-9][1-9]*
MCS123G  MCS345B
```

But it'll not give you the first file, since you have `[1-9]` instead of `[0-9]`.

As documented in [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html), you'll need to use `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:alpha]]`

```
$ ls MCS[[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]
MCS023A  MCS123G  MCS345B
```